# Update a table in a partial view using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I want to update a table using a string parameter from a selectList. The parameter "nomMethode" gets passed on correctly to the action "GetDebitsByMethodPartial" in the controller "TypeEssaiController". I am getting the correct number of results in _viewModel.Debits but I don't know how to update the table. Please help

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <form asp-controller="TypeEssai">
        <div>
            <b>Nom de la méthode</b>
        </div>
        <select asp-for="Methode.NomMethode"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.methodesList,"CodeMethode","NomMethode"))" onchange="postMethodeName()">
            <option>Veuillez choisir</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="_GetDebitsByMethod">
    <partial name="_GetDebitsByMethod.cshtml" model="Model.Debits" />
</div>
```

On changing the selectList, postMethodeName gets called.

**Javascript Jquery**

I believe the issue is also related to $("#_tbDebits").html(data) after the success.

```
function postMethodeName() {
            var nomMethode = $('#Methode_NomMethode option:selected').text();
            console.log(nomMethode);
            console.log("postmethod called");
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(nomMethode),
                url: "/TestAjmal/GetDebitsByMethodPartial/" + nomMethode,
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#_tbDebits").html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                    alert("ajax returned success")
                }
            }).done(function (data) {
                console.log(data.result);
            })
        }
```

**The Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult GetDebitsByMethodPartial([FromBody] string nomMethode)
    {
        _viewModel.Debits = (from methode in _context.Methode
                             join debit in _context.Debit on methode.NomMethode equals nomMethode
                             where debit.NomDeLaMethode == nomMethode
                             select new Debit { PositionDebit = debit.PositionDebit, NomDeLaMethode = debit.NomDeLaMethode, Debits = debit.Debits, CoefficientDePonderation = debit.CoefficientDePonderation }).ToList();
        return PartialView("_GetDebitsByMethod", _viewModel.Debits);
    }
```

**The partial view**

The model is an IEnumerable of an object

```
@model IEnumerable<TestAjmalApp.Debit>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table class="table" id="_tbDebits">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PositionDebit)</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NomDeLaMethode)</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Debits)</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CoefficientDePonderation)</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Jauge)</a>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PositionDebit)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomDeLaMethode)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Debits)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoefficientDePonderation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Jauge)
                        </td>
                        <!--<td>
                            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.PositionDebit">Edit</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Debits">Details</a> |
                            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CoefficientDePonderation">Delete</a>
                        </td>-->
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please notice, that in your jquery you are using `_tbDebits` but your table got the id `tbDebits`, so my guess would be to remove `_` from `$("#_tbDebits")`

Comment: I noticed it too. I changed it but it is still not working.Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the `console.log(data)` return something?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Oops no :)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I think it is because I am not returning a JSONResult

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Now it is console.logging the results. Now I need to append to the table because it is overwriting it.You know how ?  :)

Comment: try with `$("#tbDebits").append(data);`